# Combining the effects of regression coefficients

Tags: regression

In a simple linear regression, if y = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3....usually we interpret the beta regression coefficients individually. EX: if x1 is height and x3 is dollars ... we say that 1 unit increase in height has a b1 increase on the response y, and a 1 unit increase in dollars has a b3 increase on response y.

As I understand, it is not correct to say that a 1 unit increase in height AND a 1 unit increase in dollars have a b1+b3 increase on the y variable. I think this is because of independence assumption of regression. To do this, you need an interaction term, ex:  = b0 + b1x1 + b2x2 + b3x3 + b4x1x3.

This is the same in logistic regression, is it possible to say the odds ratio of e^(b1+b3) ... or is this not correct? Can we do this? I am having a lot of trouble understanding how regression coeffecients can be understood together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just see for yourself whether the math works out. See what happens when you simultaneously increase the value of two predictors by 1. I'll show you what I mean:

Let's say we have our logistic regression model$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_3
$$
This model assumes there is no interaction on the log odds scale. Let's figure out the predicted odds for some set of values of $X_1$ and $X_2$, say $x_1$ and $x_2$, and find the predicted odds when we increase the value of both variables by 1. Note we will hold $X_3$ constant at a value of $x_3$.

So the predicted odds when setting $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $x_1$ and $x_2$ is$$
\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3}
$$
The predicted odds when setting $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $x_1 + 1$ and $x_2 + 1$ is$$
\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_3}
$$
When we take the ratio of these odds, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_3}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3}}
&=e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_3) - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3)}\\ &= e^{\beta_1 + \beta_2}
\end{align}
So, yes, the odds ratio corresponding to increase both $x_1$ and $x_2$ by 1 simultaneously is the sum of the coefficients.

When there is an interaction in the model, things are a little different. Let's say our model for the log odds is
$$
\log\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \beta_3 X_1 X_2
$$
(This time I'm leaving out $X_3$ since we saw its coefficient isn't relevant unless it also interacts with $X_1$ or $X_2$.)

Now we have that the predicted odds when setting $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $x_1$ and $x_2$ is
$$
\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2}
$$

The predicted odds when setting $X_1$ and $X_2$ to $x_1 + 1$ and $x_2 + 1$ is
$$
\frac{p}{1-p}=e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 + \beta_3 x_2 + \beta_3}
$$

When we take the ratio of these odds, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 + \beta_3 x_2 + \beta_3}}{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2}} &= e^{(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 + \beta_3 x_2 + \beta_3) - (\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_1 x_2)} \\ &= e^{\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3 x_1 + \beta_3 x_2 + \beta_3}
\end{align}

This is all math you can do yourself. When in doubt, you can always just see what happens when you increase the value of two predictors by 1 instead of taking your instructor or someone else's word for it.